# How to show all posts by author on buddypress profile with navigation

Tags: posts, loop, buddypress, profiles

I'm using Buddypress for wordpress and I'm trying to show a loop on the profile page of a user. I use infinite scroll to load more pages but the link to page 2 doesn't point to a group of posts and instead takes me to a blank page template but I do get this link.

```
"http://mysite.com/exampleuser/page/2"
```

Any ideas on how to make this page correctly? The following snippet is placed in the `profile-loop.php`.

```
<?php
  global $bp;
  global $paged;
  global $wp_query;
  $temp = $wp_query;
  $wp_query = null;
  $user_id = $bp->displayed_user->id;
  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 16,
        'cat' => -1,
        'post_type' => array( 
            'post',
            'fod_videos',
            'fod_music',
            'fod_articles',
            'fod_albums'  
         ),
        'author' => $user_id,
        'paged' => $paged
    );
  $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
  while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :   $wp_query->the_post();
     get_template_part( 'loop', 'contents' );
  endwhile;
  echo '<div class="infinitescroll">';
    next_posts_link('Next');
  echo '</div>';
  $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;
 ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var href = 'first';
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#boxes').infinitescroll({
        loading: {
          finished: undefined,
          finishedMsg: '',
          img: '',
          msgText: '',
          speed: 'fast',
          start: undefined
        },
        navSelector: '.infinitescroll',
        nextSelector: '.infinitescroll a',
        itemSelector: '#boxes .box',
        bufferPx     : 120,
        debug: false
    }, function(arrayOfNewElems) {
       var $newElems = $( arrayOfNewElems ).css({opacity: 0});
       $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $newElems.animate({opacity: 1});
        $('#boxes').masonry('appended', $newElems, true);
        if(href != $('.infinitescroll a').attr('href')) {
            href = $('.infinitescroll a').attr('href');
        }
      });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

(btw hi boone, im jacob, from vancouver). ( keyword "nice!" :)

I am facing the exact same problem. Your implementation of the infinitescroll plugin seems ok. but it doesn seem to be an inifinitescroll prob to me.  btw I disabled it, by simply uncommenting my item container and when i try to navigate through the pages with my navigation links, as soon as i get on page 2 I have a 404 (which is exactly what firebugs spits in the console, if you have the infinitescroll turned on)

I have setup my loop as Pollux did.

If I retrieve the page param via a

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

from members/single/home.php I get

"Call to a member function get() on a non-object" error.

So for now, I just disabled the page param and managed to make it work by going into permalink settings and putting them back to the default /?p=123

I can now access home.php via the URL /members/USER  and get a nice view of the buddypress profile, with all the user´s posts listed next to it. It nicely moves over to ?paged=2,3,4,5,etc. and also infinitescroll can handle everything.

This is no solution though, as I terribly need permalinks to be structured per /sample-post/ and buddypress even expects me to do that.

I am relatively new to the world of wordpress and buddypress and thus only can share my experience til now. I still hope Boon or somebody else might get enlightend by this experience.

nice greetings,

kubante

Comment: This is obviously a wp_rewrite issue. I have the same issue but with bbPress, pagination was not working on user profile with pretty permalinks `/forums/users/username/page/2/`, but works fine with default settings `/?bbp_user=1&paged=2`. Unfortunately my knowledge in that subject is limited, but I know that a new rewrite rule must be added so that server will recognize the pagination on pretty permalinks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your infinite scroll script interacts with `WP_Query`. But the root problem appears to be that you're not providing a `paged` parameter for `WP_Query`, which is the parameter responsible for setting which page you're looking at. If you don't provide such a parameter, it defaults to `1`, which would describe the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Thx Boone for answering. How would you go about setting up the loop? I added `'paged' => get_query_var('page')` but it didn't help. Was that what you meant? You can see the new loop above in the update. I tried both "page" and "paged".

Comment: It's not really possible for me to say, without knowing more about how you're implementing infinite scroll.

Comment: Basically I'm using the jquery masonry and infinite scroll jquery plugins to list posts. I have a loop that I run using the same template on my index page for all recent posts for my site and that works perfectly Which made me curious so I took out `'author' => $user_id` from this loop and ran it on the index page and it worked perfectly. But that same loop on a profile page still only triggers the first page. You can see the script I use to trigger infinite scroll above in the example.